# Using keypress and the or function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm tying to configure my app to click "Enter" div, when the "Enter" button on the keyboard is pressed. I already have the Enter div and it works when I click it with the mouse. I believe I need to use the keypress function with event listener and the logical OR | | operator. but I could not get it working, not even sure if I am in the correct direction, Thanks alot for the help. My code is as follows.

```js
let display = document.getElementById("display");
let validKeys = [
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  "0",
  "Enter",
  "Clear",
];
let pin = "";

document.getElementById("pin-pad").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (!validKeys.includes(event.target.innerText)) {
    return;
  }

  if (event.target.innerText === "Enter") {
    window.electronAPI.sendPin(pin);
    return;
  }

  if (event.target.innerText === "Clear") {
    pin = display.value = "";
    return;
  }

  pin = pin + event.target.innerText;
  display.value = "*".repeat(pin.length);
});

///tests
const handlekeyUp = function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  const input = document.getElementById("display");
  console.log(input, e.key, input.value);
  var reg = new RegExp("^[0-9]$");
  const number = document.querySelector(`[data-number="${e.key}"]`);

  if (reg.test(e.key)) input.value += e.key;
  if (number) number.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
};

const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
  const number = document.querySelector(`[data-number="${e.key}"]`);
  if (!number) {
    return;
  }
  number.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
};

document.addEventListener("keyup", handlekeyUp);

document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input type="password" id="display" disabled />

    <div id="pin-pad">
      <div data-number="1">1</div>
      <div data-number="2">2</div>
      <div data-number="3">3</div>
      <div data-number="4">4</div>
      <div data-number="5">5</div>
      <div data-number="6">6</div>
      <div data-number="7">7</div>
      <div data-number="8">8</div>
      <div data-number="9">9</div>
      <div>Enter</div>
      <div data-number="0">0</div>
      <div>Clear</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if it is only me but I don't understand the issue. Is there anything specific you're asking?

Comment: I'n short, I have an enter button (div) it works when I click it with the mouse, I also want to to work when I hit the enter on keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.keyCode` in your `handlekeyUp` event handler to determine which key is pressed and if the *Enter* key is pressed, then send the same instruction when the word *Enter* is clicked:

```js
document.getElementById("pin-pad").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.innerText === "Enter") {
    //window.electronAPI.sendPin(pin);
    console.log('click Enter')
    return;
  }
})

const handlekeyUp = function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  if ( 13 === e.keyCode ) { // Enter key
    //window.electronAPI.sendPin(pin);
    console.log('keypress Enter')
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", handlekeyUp);
```

```html
<div id="pin-pad">
  <div>Enter</div>
</div>
```

---

Refactoring your code and including click word "Enter" word, and keypress Enter key:

```js
const handleKey = (event) => {
  const key = event.key || event.target.innerText;
  if (!/^([0-9]|Enter|Clear|Escape)$/.test(key)) { return; }
  handleKeyOut(event);

  const display = document.getElementById("display");

  if (key === "Enter") {
    console.log("sendPin", display.value);
    //window.electronAPI.sendPin(display.value);
    return;
  }

  if (key === "Clear" || key === "Escape") {
    pin = display.value = "";
    return;
  }

  display.value += key;
}

const handleKeyOver = (event) => {
  const key = event.key || event.target.innerText;
  const number = document.querySelector(`[data-key="${key}"]`);
  if (!number) { return; }
  number.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
};

const handleKeyOut = (event) => {
  const key = event.key || event.target.innerText;
  const number = document.querySelector(`[data-key="${key}"]`);
  if (!number) { return; }
  number.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
};

document.getElementById("pin-pad").addEventListener("click", handleKey);
document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKey);
document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyOver);
document.querySelectorAll("[data-key]").forEach((divkey) => {
  divkey.addEventListener("mouseover", handleKeyOver);
  divkey.addEventListener("mouseout", handleKeyOut);
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input type="password" id="display" disabled />

    <div id="pin-pad">
      <div data-key="1">1</div><div data-key="2">2</div><div data-key="3">3</div>
      <div data-key="4">4</div><div data-key="5">5</div><div data-key="6">6</div>
      <div data-key="7">7</div><div data-key="8">8</div><div data-key="9">9</div>
      <div data-key="0">0</div>
      <div data-key="Enter">Enter</div><div data-key="Clear">Clear</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added to my code but it did not work as intended to. user must be able to login when hit enter on keyboard ( if password is correct)

Comment: So I trimmed down the code to show you a working example how to solve the *specific problem you stated in your question*. Are you saying you don't know how to incorporate the code `if ( 13 === e.keyCode ) { window.electronAPI.sendPin(pin); }` into your login code?

Comment: That is true, I could not put the code in the correct place :(

Comment: Put it at the end of your `handlekeyUp` event handler function. Also, if my answer solves the specific problem in your question accept my answer so others can benefit from it. Then ask another question if you still need help.

Comment: HandlekeyUp function looks as following. but I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendPin')
    at HTMLDocument.handlekeyUp (pin-pad:85:28)
handlekeyUp @ pin-pad:85
   ` ementById("display");
      console.log(input, e.key, input.value);
      var reg = new RegExp("^[0-9]$");
      const number = document.querySelector(`[data-number="${e.key}"]`);
      if (reg.test(e.key)) input.value += e.key;
      if (number) number.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
      if (13 === e.keyCode) {
        window.electronAPI.sendPin(pin);
      }
    };`